# The differences between a string and an element of a vector<string>

Tags: c++, string, vector

I'm a newcomer to programming. I am learning `vector` in C++. I am curious about why `string s = 42;` causes error but

```
vector<string>vec(3);
vec[0] = 42;
```

does not. Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`std::vector` has nothing to do with that, your sample with `std::vector` is similar to

```
std::string s;
s = 42;
```

but

```
std::string s = 42; // Constructor: "equivalent" to std::string s = std::string(42)
```

is different than

```
std::string s;
s = 42; // assignation: s.operator =(42)
```

and `std::string::operator=(char)` exists whereas constructor taking `char` doesn't.

Comment: and an int is implicitly castable to a char

Comment: @Steve Correct terminology would be "implicitly convertible", casts are always explicit.

Answer (score 6):

`std::vector` is a red herring. If you simply try the following, it will also compile fine :

```
#include <string>
int main()
{
    std::string str;
    str = 42;
}
```

What you are actually doing is using [`std::string::operator=(char)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%3D) which assigns a single character to the string. `42` is implicitly convertible to `char`. According to the ascii table, the value 42 is represented by the `'*'` character. We can verify this with the following :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main()
{
    std::string str;
    str = 42;
    std::cout << str; // Prints *
}
```